# Unable to access SSH via securegateway

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am trying to expose an SSH port from my local system to a Bluemix service via securegateway.

I can see the securegateway client showing as connected. On my client, my acl allows port 22 from all.

I have a securegateway destination set up with my local machine's IP and ssh port.

However when I connect to the cloudhost:port for this ssh destination, the connection times out. There is no firewall blocking access to port 22 on the local machine and I've confirmed that SSH is indeed listening.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You might have better luck asking this on [sf] or [unix.se].

Comment: I was sent here with via a link from Bluemix, I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be the iptables rules on the Bluemix WebSphere server that were blocking outbound SSH connections.

Answer (score 0):

Which Secure Gateway client are you using?  If the connection is fine between the SG client and the SG server, it could be that the client can't actually reach the IP:Port provided during the destination creation, usually caused by the client environment being unable to resolve the path to the IP/host.  This should cause some errors to be generated on the client, as well.

If nothing is even making it to the client, then the issue would likely be with how you are trying to connect to the cloud host:port.  Can you provide some more details about the destination you created (cloud vs on-prem, protocol, etc)?

With this info, I can try to provide a more specific solution.

Comment: I solved it. There was an issue with the firewall on the Bluemix WAS server blocking outbound connections.

Thank you for your help!